# Automatic List Views

Tags: list, view

**The Basics:**

I have got to separate List.

List 1: Problems

List 2: Ideas

Every Idea is related to a Problem and both lists are very dynamic.

**The Question**:

Is it possible to create a view automatically if a new Problem is posted?

What i want to achieve is by clicking a specific Problem having the opportunity (Button, Link, etc.) to show all the Ideas related to this Problem.

Answer (score 0):

With code the solution is easy. Write a list item event receiver that catches on item added and on item deleted. (Maybe updated to in case the name is changed.) Then you can dynamically create views on your other list by creating a new `SPView` for each on added that is called. On deleted you delete them.